Let $A \subset \Re$ be non-empty and bounded. Show there exists an $x \in A$ such that $x > \sup A - \epsilon$.
Let $A \subset \Re$ be non-empty and bounded and show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $x \in A$ such that $x > \sup A - \epsilon$. Now the question is how can I prove this statement (preferably by contradiction)?
I attempted this problem in two different ways. In one approach I reason such an $x$ must exist by finding an instance of an $x$ which meets the requirements. In the other approach I attempted to prove such an $x$ exists by contradiction, namely by assuming that no such element exists yet finding that such an element does indeed exist.
Here's the first approach. Let $m = \max A$ be the greatest element in $A$, i.e. $x \leq m$ for all $x \in A$. Since $A \subset \Re$ we get that $m = \sup A$ which means $m > \sup A - \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. And so if we take $x = m$ we have that $x \in A$ and $x > \sup A - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, which concludes the proof.
And now the approach based on contradiction. I assume that there is no $x \in A$ such that $x > \sup A - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Now, let $m = \max A$ as before. Then $m \in A$, $m = \sup A$ and $m > \sup A - \epsilon$. Take $x = m$ and then we have $x > \sup A - \epsilon$, a contradiction. And so there indeed exists an $x \in A$ such that $x > \sup A - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

You’ve got the original statement very wrong. Read carefully for proper quantifiers.

Beware that the maximum does not always exist... For instance, if $A=(0,1)$ what is $\max A$?

@TedShifrin In what way am I getting it wrong?

The negation would be that $x \le \sup A - \epsilon$ for all $x \in A$. Hence $\sup A - \epsilon$ would be an upper bound.

For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $x$ …. As you stated it, the result holds if and only if $A$ has a largest element.

@TedShifrin Let's say we have $x \in A$ and $A$ has an open interval $A = (0,1)$ and we define $$\max A = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} x$$ Then $\max A = 1$ in this case. Would this work? It seems to me like it would. In this scenario we have $x \in A$ and $x$ is arbitrarily close to $\sup A$.

Yes, your original version required that there be a single $x$ that works for every $\epsilon$. When $A$ has a largest element, the sup equals the max. But otherwise there is no $x$ that satisfies the condition.

I don't want to sound arrogant but I think that you are misunderstanding several concepts. I will try to explain where you are wrong.
In your first approach. You said ''let $m = \max A$'', in this sentence you are saying ''let $m = \sup A$ and $m \in A$''. The difference between the supremum and maximum is that every supremum IS the maximum, but the maximum not always exists (and for sets of real numbers we just need bounded above for the existence of the supremum). In short words, the maximum is the supremum when the last one belong to the set. For example, the interval $(0,1)$ has a supremum and it's $1$, but doesn't have a maximum. Now, if we considered the interval $(0,1]$ then the supremum and the maximum of the set is $1$. Furthermore, even if your set $A$ has a maximum, your argument to prove the stament is that $m > \sup A - \epsilon$, this is trivially true and you didn't prove nothing because $m = \sup A$.
Now your approach by contradiction. Your negation is wrong, to see this, first write your statement in symbols
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists x \in A : \sup A - \epsilon < x \leqslant \sup A
\end{align}
if you want to deny this, we have the next statement
\begin{align}
\exists \epsilon \leqslant 0 , \forall x \in A : x \leqslant \sup A - \epsilon
\end{align}
from this you could get a contradiction. And again, I think that you are misunderstanding the concepts of supremum and maximum.
